Help with substitution of trigonometric expression in another and simplifying it
Given
$(1+e)^2=(\cos\theta+\gamma\sin\theta)^2+\sin^2\theta$
and
$\tan\theta = \tan\phi/(1-\gamma\tan\phi)$,
how can it be shown that
$e = (1-2\gamma\sin\phi\cos\phi+\gamma^2\cos^2\phi)^{-1/2}-1$,
where $e$ is strain, $\theta$ is initial angle of a line, $\gamma$ is shear strain and $\phi$ is final angle of a line.

What have you tried? Do you have any ideas? Any guesses?

@ultralegend5385 tried replacing $\sin\theta = \tan\phi$ and $\cos\theta = (1-\gamma\tan\phi)$ but that will just end with $e = (1+\tan^2\phi)^{1/2}-1$

You attempted to put $\sin\theta=\tan\phi$, $\cos\theta=1-\gamma\tan\phi$ but that may not be true, because
$$(\tan\phi)^2+(1-\gamma\tan\phi)^2\neq1$$
in general. If $a/b=c/d$, you cannot say $a=c$ and $b=d$. But you can say $a=\lambda c$ and $b=\lambda d$. In your case, you have $\sin\theta=\lambda\tan\phi$ and $\cos\theta=\lambda(1-\gamma\tan\phi)$. You can find $\lambda$ by the equation $(\sin\theta)^2+(\cos\theta)^2=1$. Then, you should get what you want.

But that is tedious. Even then, I encourage you try that and get your answer. But I will put here (in spoiler) another method, which is slightly easier to handle the computations with

 $$(\cos\theta+\gamma\sin\theta)^2+\sin^2\theta=\cos^2\theta\big((1+\gamma\tan\theta)^2+\tan^2\theta\big)=\frac{(1+\gamma\tan\theta)^2+\tan^2\theta}{1+\tan^2\theta}$$

Hope this helps. :)

The first suggestion led to $\lambda = \sqrt{1/(\tan^2\phi+1-2\gamma\tan\phi+\gamma^2\tan^2\phi)}$ and then a huge expression for $\sin^2\theta$, $\cos^2\theta$ and $2\cos\theta\sin\theta$. From then on there is $\tan^2\theta = \sin^2\phi/(\cos^2\phi-2\gamma\sin\phi\cos\phi+\gamma^2\sin^2\phi)$. Subtituting this in the latter suggestion you shared still doesn't lead to the simplifcation expected.

I'm representing $\theta$ as $x$,$\gamma$ as $y$,$\phi$ as $z$ for easy typing.
$$(1+e)^2=(\cos x+y\sin x)^2+\sin^2 x\\
=1+2y\cos x\sin x + y^2\sin^2 x \\
(e+1)^2=1+y(\sin 2x + y\sin^2x)...(i)$$
Now
$$\cot x=\cot z-y \implies \sin^2 x=\frac{1}{(\cot z-y)^2+1}$$
Again, $\sin 2x=\frac{2\tan x}{1+\tan^2 x}$, so
$$\sin 2x=-\frac{2 (y - \cot(z))}{(\cot z-y)^2+1}=2(\cot z-y)\sin^2x$$ ( I got this value by simply putting the equation your provide in place of $\tan x$)
We input them in $(i)$ to get
$$(e+1)^2=1+y\bigg(\frac{-2y+2\cot z + y}{(\cot z-y)^2+1}\bigg)$$
$$\implies (e+1)^2=\frac{(\cot z -y)^2+1-y^2+2y\cot z}{(\cot z-y)^2+1}=\frac{\csc^2z}{(\cot z-y)^2+1}=\csc^2 z \sin^2 x$$
Thus $e=±\csc z \sin x -1$
It seems quite difficult to reach your answer. Still I think I have provided some simplification
